# How to add multiple values to data.frame without loop?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, subset

Suppose I have matrix D which consists of death counts per year by specific ages.

I want to fill this matrix with appropriate death counts that is stored in 
vector Age, but the following code gives me wrong answer. How should I write the code without making a loop?

```
# Year and age grid for tables
Years=c(2007:2017)
Ages=c(60:70)

#Data.frame of deaths
D=data.frame(matrix(ncol=length(Years),nrow=length(Ages)));  D[is.na(D)]=0 
colnames(D)=Years
rownames(D)=Ages

Age=c(60,61,62,65,65,65,68,69,60)
year=2010

D[as.character(Age),as.character(year)]<-
D[as.character(Age),as.character(year)]+1
D[,'2010'] # 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
# Should be  2 1 1 0 0 3 0 0 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `table`

```
AgeTable = table(Age)
D[names(AgeTable), as.character(year)] = AgeTable
D[,'2010']
[1] 2 1 1 0 0 3 0 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: That solution work`s for this problem. But i need the solution wich can accumulate previous table colums.

Comment: @Sattel Well,  how do you have the data stored for the previous years? Please provide data that allows us to respond to your actual problem.

Comment: Suppose i have a line of code like this, and my data is. I have multiple replications of age for each call. But the code doesnt accumulate it. Data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxtjNizJ0NDlWmdsb3NRVzhDUm8      PY[as.character(died.after.bd$Age),as.character(year)]=(as.numeric(((died.after.bd$Death-died.after.bd$bd
                                                                         )
                                                                      /365.25))+ PY[as.character(died.after.bd$Age),as.character(year)])